# Mongo object's id as uploadings dirname in CarrierWave

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid, carrierwave

I'm using Sinatra with Mongoid and CarrierWave. I need to store document's attachments in */public/attachments/DOCUMENTS_ID*.

Model of Mongo document:

```
class Dcmnt
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: 'dcmnts'
  field :published,   type: Boolean
  field :name,        type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :additional,  type: String
  field :created_at,  type: Date
  mount_uploader :attachment, Uploader, type: String
end
```

And action's code:

```
  post '/admin/create' do
    params.delete 'submit'
    d = Dcmnt.new(
      :published   => params[:published],
      :name        => params[:name],
      :description => params[:description],
      :additional  => params[:additional],
      :created_at  => Time.now
    )
    d.attachment = params[:photos]
    d.save
  end
```

When I'm setting up unloader like this:

```
class Uploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    'public/attachments/' + d.id
  end
end
```

It doesn't works for some *amzaing* reason. Can you help me implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing models attributes in CarrierWave is provided via *model* key word

```
class Uploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    'attachments/' + model.id
  end
end
```